Images missing after navigating WinUI3/UWP
so I have a ListView with items. The DataTemplate contains a Rectangle. The Fill Brush is binded via a Converter which returns a new ImageBrush if the binded url is not null. If it is though the converter will return a Placeholder Brush:
public class StringImageBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    readonly Brush placeholderBrush = new LinearGradientBrush([
        new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromArgb(144, 96, 96, 96), Offset = 0 },
        new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromArgb(10, 96, 96, 96), Offset = 1 },
        ], 45);


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) =>
        value is string imageUrl ? new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new(imageUrl)) } : placeholderBrush;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}

<DataTemplate x:DataType="plgm:SearchResult">
    <Grid Padding="12">
        <Rectangle
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Fill="{x:Bind ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource StringImageBrushConverter}}"
            RadiusX="4"
            RadiusY="4" />

        <TextBlock
            Margin="62,5,90,0"
            Style="{StaticResource FlyoutPickerTitleTextBlockStyle}"
            Text="{x:Bind Title}"
            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        <TextBlock
            Margin="62,26,90,0"
            Foreground="{ThemeResource TextFillColorSecondaryBrush}"
            Text="{x:Bind Artists}"
            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />

        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="{ThemeResource TextFillColorSecondaryBrush}"
            Text="{x:Bind Duration, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanStringConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>


This works great - until navigating to a different page and then back to it. Then some images are completely gone (when scrolling they will appear since the Virtualization will recreate them). The behavior looks random to me, since its always different entries.

Here is what it looks like:

I have created a sample project here: GitHub

Is it WinUI3 or UWP they're not the same. And do you have a reproducing project?

@SimonMourier It is WinUI3 and as far as I know the binding works exactly the same in WinUI3 and UWP. Never noticed any difference between them. I have created a sample project here: GitHub. During that I have noticed that the issue only occurs when the Rectangle has a radius set.

UWP is now frozen for like 2/3 years. WinUI3 evolves. Works fine for me, although it can take quite a time to complete since it's backed by images on a web server. You don't need a rectangle + converter, you should be able to do it like this:  <Border CornerRadius="4" Width="50" Height="50"><Border.Background><ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind ImageUrl}" /></Border.Background></Border> and it might perform better

I do need the converter since the imageUrl may be null. Thats why I have a placeholder brush. And are you sure it works fine for you? The behavior is quite random (as seen in the gif). I have tested Border, Grid & Rectangle as the image container but as soon as I apply any corner radius the images disappear on navigating back to the page.

Yes, it works fine, I know what I'm saying, but as said, it can take time to complete, it has inertia as demonstrated in the end of this video where I wait seconds before it completes https://i.imgur.com/rDRm2Bj.mp4 Using XAML like I shown exhibits better performance because it's cached. You can use two XAML Border and play with Visibility binding if you want to display different things depending on your object.

Im not sure if I described my problem correctly. Your video doesn't describe my issue. The issue happens when navigating back to the page.
Steps to reproduce:

Scroll a bit around, load a few images;
Navigate to the "Page With Nothing";
Navigate back to the "Page With List";
Some of the images are missing and they wont load, no matter how long you wait.

Im not quite sure but the arent the images cached even with a converter (thats why the property "CreateOptions" exists and its not set to "IgnoreImageCache". Having 2 Borders with a visibility binding seems inefficient.

I cannot access URLs in the sample, so I use local pictures instead. In the case of local pictures, I cannot reproduce the issue.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT I was able to reproduce this issue even with local files. I have uploaded a gif here: Imgur. Did you follow the reproducing steps?

I tested again and reproduced the issue. You can also report it at https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues.
